# Build path error in eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse

whenever I do a Clean on my project, I got 2 errors:->

```
1.) the project is missing gen folder
2.) there is a build path error.
```

I go to "Configure build path" and uncheck "Android 1.6". It works. If I do this again , i go and this time check "Android 1.6". It again works.

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check it - Build Automatically Option ..

Comment: he mean uncheck it.so uncheck it

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means uncheck it.