# Eclipse 3.5 + ADT: build path errors

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, buildpath

I am using Eclipse 3.5 for Jave EE Developers. Plugins installed include: Android Development Tools, Adobe Flash Builder 4, PDT, PyDev. I have problem with running the application I built.

I can start a new project, add a button, and run it on an AVD. Then I add another button, try to run it on AVD, and Eclipse says **1) gen folder is missing**, **2) there are errors with build path**.

I can get ride of the first error by simply refreshing the project in the left pane, but the second error always sticks around. I searched [online](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f4/new-developer-small-problems-need-help-29532/) and on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029679/android-helloworld-build-path-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551591/build-path-error-in-eclipse-for-android), although several people have the same problem, there is no definite solution I can find.

Can somebody who fixed this problem successfully tell me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

> a)Delete your project from Eclipse (**i
>   said ONLY from Eclipse**, so uncheck
>   option: Delete project contents on
>   disk)
>
> b) import your project to Eclipse:
>   file > Import > Existing Projects into
>   Workspace (Look for your project
>   previously deleted from Eclipse) >
>   Finish

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work. Is this a temporary workaround or permanent solution?